# need help in generating report in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program which analyses some information in runtime and save the analysis results in certain variables. I have 15 of these variables, of which, 13 are string type, 1 integer and 1 bitmap image. I want to let the user to generate a report based on the analysis data. I have been trying to search the forums for help, but couldn't find a proper solution yet.
First of all, I don't want to save these analysed results in a database (SQL etc). All i want to do is just to display the report to the user based on analysis results and let him save or print it.

This is what I did so far based on numerous hints that I get from forums. I added a report.rdlc file and created a template for the report. I also created a dataset.xsd file and added the analysis parameters to the dataset. All the dataset values are added to the report template.

Now this is where I am stuck. I don't have an idea how to proceed from here and generate a report. Right now what my program does is, upon button click, the analysed parameters will be saved in their respective variables that I specified in the main program. What I want to achieve is to use these results and generate a report as in the template. Sorry that I am not able to post images here due to the user restriction.

Any guidance on how to achieve this is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Need little bit of something to work on - like code, if you have a problem it will be solvable. If you need tutorial, please google.

Comment: This is way too generic.  What medium do you want the report?  Pdf? Excel?  What does the template look like?  Most importantly, where's your code for the loop that iterates the database records?  That's key.  Flesh out your question or it will get closed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, reports support parameters which can be injected via the presentation control.

With little else to go on, I would look here first.